# Do i have to initialize ArrayAdapter at each listView update

Tags: java, android, listview, click, android-timepicker

I want to update the list view inside click events but because I add the items inside a function that is outside the oncreate(), calls inside the click events dont update the listview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    List<String> itemlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Initializing the array lists and the adapter
        Button add = findViewById(R.id.add);
        EditText editText = findViewById (R.id.editText);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView);
        Button delete = findViewById (R.id.delete);
        Button clear = findViewById(R.id.clear);


        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter (MainActivity.this, android.
        R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, itemlist);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {

                   TimePickerFragment timePicker =  new TimePickerFragment();
                   timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"time picker");
                   //If i add items like this, everyting works fine 
//                   itemlist.add(editText.getText().toString());
//                   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                   // This is because every time when you add the item the input      space or the eidt text space will be cleared
//                   editText.getText().clear();
               }
           }
        );


        // Selecting and Deleting the items from the list when the delete button is pressed

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SparseBooleanArray position = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();


                Integer count = listView.getCount();
                int item = count - 1;
                while (item >= 0) {
                if (position.get(item)) {
                    itemlist.remove(item);
//                    adapter.remove(itemlist.get(item));
                }
                item--;
                }
                position.clear();
                ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, itemlist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        // Clearing all the items in the list when the clear button is pressed
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                itemlist.clear();
                ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, itemlist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
        itemlist.add("The time selected is "+i+":"+i1);

        ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);

        
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, itemlist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}t.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, itemlist);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
        itemlist.add("The time selected is "+i+":"+i1);

        ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);

        /// TODO: Make adapter accessible from here, dont create a local one
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, itemlist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) ;

            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute,android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

        }
}
```

When i add items like in the commented part, i dont have to initialize adapter each time. I can use the same adapter but when i add items inside ontimeset i have to initialize a new adapter (i tried using adapter as a class member but didnt work) and because of this i think, the updates inside oncreate doesnt change the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just define your adapter once in your `onCreate()` and update it from anywhere, just make sure it is accessible using a global variable. Just like your `itemList` is accessible from anywhere, you can just add/remove items from your list, and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` this will automatically update the list view and adapter according to your list. However make sure you attach your adapter to your list view in `onCreate()` itself.

Comment: Thanks i thought i had to initialize it at global for some reason but just declaring it fixed it.